# Assigning value to variable from struct array

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have an array of structs in my header file and I have written some code in main file.

```
char temp, index;
for (index = 0; index < 5; index++)
       temp = cards[index].foo;
```

I notice that temp gets the value of the first char but then it won't change
after that; i.e. if the first char from struct array is 'c' then it gets 'c'
but if the second char is 'f' it won't get 'f' — it will stay with 'c'.

How can I fix this?

my struct array is in my header and looks like this

```
struct x{
char foo;
 } cards[Size];
```

Comment: Please show your structure .

Comment: more detail required

Comment: If the different elements of `cards` have different values in them, then the assignment should work.  You would need to show code initializing the array, and then add printing code to loop to demonstrate your problem: `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) cards[i].foo = 'a' + i;` to initialize, and then modify your loop to `for (index = 0; index < 5; index++) { printf("c[%d].foo = %c\n", index, cards[index].foo); temp = cards[index].foo; printf("t        = %c\n", temp); }`.  Then show what it prints.  It should be showing `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`.

Comment: I agree with @JonathanLeffler . and please show some more detail so that one can help

Answer (score 1):

Hai bro i just tried your code in C it is seems to work properly....
my header file is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define Size 5

struct x
{
    char foo;
} cards[Size];
```

Main is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include"my.h"

int main()
{
    int i,index;
    char temp;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        cards[i].foo = 'a' + i;
    for (index = 0; index < 5; index++)
    {
        printf("c[%d].foo = %c\n", index, cards[index].foo);
        temp = cards[index].foo;
        printf("t = %c\n", temp);
    }

}
```

output is:

```
c[0].foo = a
t = a
c[1].foo = b
t = b
c[2].foo = c
t = c
c[3].foo = d
t = d
c[4].foo = e
t = e
```